# Adding command output list as a parameter to another (awscli)

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I want the listed output from this command:

`aws elbv2 describe-load-balancers --region eu-west-1 --query 'LoadBalancers[*].LoadBalancerArn'`

used as input added in place of [ELB-ARN] with each produced value from above:

`aws elbv2 describe-target-groups --region eu-west-1 --load-balancer-arn "[ELB-ARN]" --query 'TargetGroups[*].TargetGroupArn'`

Having the 2nd command outputted to file as text on separate lines.

Comment: Wrap it inside a `$()` like `aws elbv2 describe-target-groups --load-balancer-arn "$(aws elbv2 describe-load-balancers ...)" ...` or create a variable and use that variable. If you start building more complex commands I would suggest to follow a bash tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, the output generated by the first command comes as a list and the whole block is passed as a single string which the 2nd command cannot process. I've looked at the bash for loop as an option to the 2nd operation but my issue is that the list is not separated by new lines. ``aws elbv2 describe-load-balancers --region eu-west-1 --query 'LoadBalancers[*].[LoadBalancerArn]' --output text`` then ``for elb in "${output[@]}"; do aws elbv2 describe-target-groups --region eu-west-1 --load-balancer-arn $elb --query 'TargetGroups[*].TargetGroupArn'``

Comment: What is it actually separated by? if by whitespace you can simply do

`for opt in $(cmd1); do cmd2 $opt; done`

Comment: Yes they are seperated by whitespaces. I don't know if I understand correctly but I ran with your suggestion:
''for elb in "${output[@]}"; do aws elbv2 describe-target-groups --region eu-west-1 --load-balancer-arn $elb --query 'TargetGroups[*].TargetGroupArn'; done

Comment: ``usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]

To see help text, you can run:


  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help


Unknown options: arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-east-1:xxxxxxxxxx:loadbalancer/app/ALB-something/111111111111, arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-east-1:xxxxxxxxxx:loadbalancer/app/ALB-somethingelse/2222222222222222, arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-east-1:xxxxxxxxxx:loadbalancer/app/ALB-somethingelse/333333333333.....``

Comment: Your post, as it is, doesn't actually ask a question. It could be improved by adding a final line that asks your overall question. Also, you could improve this question by making it slightly more general: remove the "--region" argument (it's irrelevant to what you're asking) and add "--output". When I run this I get json output by default, but I'm guessing you don't. It would help to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the output you're getting from the first command is in the aws cli's "text" format. Assuming that, the general approach would be to run that first command and save the results in a variable. Then feed the contents of that variable to a `for` or `while` loop that runs the second command on each item in the list. Some aws cli commands will allow multiple space-separated inputs, but `aws elbv2 describe-target-groups help` says that --load-balancer-arn only accepts a "string" data type, by which they mean a single arn, so you'll need the loop in order to run it with one arn at a time.

Here's one way to do that:

```
loadbalancerarns=$(aws elbv2 describe-load-balancers --output text --query 'LoadBalancers[*].LoadBalancerArn')

for loadbalancerarn in $loadbalancerarns; do
  aws elbv2 describe-target-groups --output text --load-balancer-arn $loadbalancerarn;
done
```

That's good enough in this case. But the best practice way to loop over items in a list in bash is to separate the items with null characters, so you could also do this:

```
loadbalancerarns=$(aws elbv2 describe-load-balancers --output text --query 'LoadBalancers[*].LoadBalancerArn')

while IFS= read -r -d "" loadbalancerarn; do
  aws elbv2 describe-target-groups --output text --load-balancer-arn $loadbalancerarn;
done < <(echo "$loadbalancerarns" | tr -s '[[:space:]]' | tr '[[:space:]]' '\0')
```

The "< <(command)" stuff at the end is necessary to mangle your list into null-separated items because the aws cli's "text" output format uses horizontal tab characters to pretty format things.

Again, either way will work in this case. The second type of loop handles more situations and thus is safer in general.

As a bonus: you can also use xargs if you're careful with the options:

```
echo "$loadbalancerarns" | tr -s '[[:space:]]' | tr '[[:space:]]' '\0' | xargs -0 -I{} aws elbv2 describe-target-groups --output text --load-balancer-arn "{}"
```